# Given a virtual disk, get the pool it belongs to

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, windows-server, windows-server-2019

I have this monstrosity:

```
Get-Volume | ForEach-Object {
    $VolObj = $_
    $ParObj = Get-Partition | Where-Object { $_.AccessPaths -contains $VolObj.Path }
    $DiskObj = Get-Disk | Where-Object { $_.Number -eq $ParObj.DiskNumber }
    $PsDriveObj = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object { $_.Name -contains $VolObj.DriveLetter }

    Get-StoragePool -IsPrimordial $false | ForEach-Object {
        $pool = $_
        Get-PhysicalDisk -StoragePool $pool | ForEach-Object {
            $disk = $_
            if ($disk.UniqueId -eq $volume_id) {
                $pool_id = $pool.UniqueId 
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

The problem with this piece of code is in the line `if ($disk.uniqueid -eq $volume_id)`.

Instead of `$volume_id` I've tried `.SerialNumber` and `UniqueId` of the multiple objects (`VolObj`, `ParObj`, `DiskObj` and `PsDriveObj`) but these are either empty or return the wrong ID (the IDs of these objects are either `vol***` since I run it on an EC2 instance or in the format of `{...}`), so the `if` is never true.

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this?

Comment: Does someting like this work: `Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "VDisk01" | Get-StorageTier`?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks but no, it returns nothing

Comment: What about: `Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "VDisk01" | Get-StoragePool`?

Comment: @harrymc Good enough for me :) Thanks. If you want you can post as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following helped the poster with his problem:

```
Get-VirtualDisk -FriendlyName "VDisk01" | Get-StoragePool
```

References:

- [Get-StoragePool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-storagepool?view=windowsserver2019-ps)
- [Get-VirtualDisk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-virtualdisk?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: For future reference: Is there anything in the  `Get-StoragePool` docs that  suggests it can be used in combination of `Get-VirtualDisk` in this way?

Comment: `Get-StoragePool` has many variants for the multiple ways it can be called. The 9th one (!) is `Get-StoragePool ... [-VirtualDisk <CimInstance>] ...`,  which hints about this.